# page.php template file render a core gutenberg component programmatically

Tags: page-template, block-editor

Is it possible to render a Gutenberg component programmatically directly in `page.php` template file?

I don't have specific requirements and I am newbie as well in Wordpress with Gutenberg. But I was wondering if the Gutenberg components `set` through editor result in `the_content` but is there a way to load any component programmatically through template file?

Thanks.

Comment: Which kind of Components are you looking for? Take a look at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages). There you will see there are simpler components (eg. components package) which dont require much dependencies but other complex ones (eg. editor package) that require the BlockEditor to be set in a post editor.

Comment: @Alvaro - it can be any thing. For instance, lets say how about we render the `quote` Gutenberg block programmatically. Like in the template file or through JS, we render the component and send some parameter which will be set as the content of the quote.

Comment: It looks like you are looking to set the BlockEditor. Ive been testing that lately and Id say its not that easy to set up, but to some extent it can be achieved. Take a look at the [playground folder](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/playground/src) in the repo which has a minimum setup to be used outside of the post editor (no sidebar though). Also check [Frontenberg](https://github.com/tomjn/Frontenberg).